# How to correctly merge two files and count values before Fisher's test in R?

Tags: r

I am very new to R, so I apologise if this looks simple to someone.

I try to to join two files and then perform a one-sided Fisher's exact test to determine if there is a greater burden of qualifying variants in casefile or controlfile.

casefile:

```
GENE  CASE_COUNT_HET  CASE_COUNT_CH   CASE_COUNT_HOM  CASE_TOTAL_AC
ENSG00000124209   1   0   0   1
ENSG00000064703   1   1   0   9
ENSG00000171408   1   0   0   1
ENSG00000110514   1   1   1   12
ENSG00000247077   1   1   1   7
```

controlfile:

```
    GENE  CASE_COUNT_HET  CASE_COUNT_CH   CASE_COUNT_HOM  CASE_TOTAL_AC
ENSG00000124209   1   0   0   1
ENSG00000064703   1   1   0   9
ENSG00000171408   1   0   0   1
ENSG00000110514   1   1   1   12
ENSG00000247077   1   1   1   7
ENSG00000174776   1   1   0   2
ENSG00000076864   1   0   1   13
ENSG00000086015   1   0   1   25
```

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
library("argparse")
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("argparse"))

parser <- ArgumentParser()
parser$add_argument("--casefile", action="store")
parser$add_argument("--casesize", action="store", type="integer")
parser$add_argument("--controlfile", action="store")
parser$add_argument("--controlsize", action="store", type="integer")
parser$add_argument("--outfile", action="store")

args <- parser$parse_args()

case.dat<-read.delim(args$casefile, header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, sep="\t")
names(case.dat)[1]<-"GENE"
control.dat<-read.delim(args$controlfile, header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, sep="\t")
names(control.dat)[1]<-"GENE"

dat<-merge(case.dat, control.dat, by="GENE", all.x=T, all.y=T)
dat[is.na(dat)]<-0

dat$P_DOM<-0
dat$P_REC<-0

for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  
  #Dominant model
  case_count<-dat[i,]$CASE_COUNT_HET+dat[i,]$CASE_COUNT_HOM
  control_count<-dat[i,]$CONTROL_COUNT_HET+dat[i,]$CONTROL_COUNT_HOM
  
  if(case_count>args$casesize){
    case_count<-args$casesize
  }else if(case_count<0){
    case_count<-0
   }
  if(control_count>args$controlsize){
    control_count<-args$controlsize
  }else if(control_count<0){
    control_count<-0
   }
  
  mat<-cbind(c(case_count, (args$casesize-case_count)), c(control_count, (args$controlsize-control_count)))
  dat[i,]$P_DOM<-fisher.test(mat, alternative="greater")$p.value
and problem starts in here:

  case_count<-dat[i,]$CASE_COUNT_HET+dat[i,]$CASE_COUNT_HOM
  control_count<-dat[i,]$CONTROL_COUNT_HET+dat[i,]$CONTROL_COUNT_HOM
```

the result of case_count and control_count is NULL values, however corresponding columns in both input files are NOT empty.

I tried to run the script above with assigning absolute numbers (1000 and 2000) to variables case_count and control_count , and the script worked without issues.

The main purpose of the code:
https://github.com/mhguo1/TRAPD

> Run burden testing This script will run the actual burden testing. It
> performs a one-sided Fisher's exact test to determine if there is a
> greater burden of qualifying variants in cases as compared to controls
> for each gene. It will perform this burden testing under a dominant
> and a recessive model.
>
> It requires R; the script was tested using R v3.1, but any version of
> R should work. The script should be run as: Rscript burden.R
> --casefile casecounts.txt --casesize 100 --controlfile controlcounts.txt --controlsize 60000 --output burden.out.txt
>
> The script has 5 required options:
>
> --casefile: Path to the counts file for the cases, as generated in Step 2A
> --casesize: Number of cases that were tested in Step 2A
> --controlfile: Path to the counts file for the controls, as generated in Step 2B
> --controlsize: Number of controls that were tested in Step 2B. If using ExAC or gnomAD, please refer to the respective documentation for
> total sample size
> --output: Output file path/name Output: A tab delimited file with 10 columns:
>
> #GENE: Gene name CASE_COUNT_HET: Number of cases carrying heterozygous qualifying variants in a given gene CASE_COUNT_CH: Number of cases
> carrying potentially compound heterozygous qualifying variants in a
> given gene CASE_COUNT_HOM: Number of cases carrying homozygous
> qualifying variants in a given gene. CASE_TOTAL_AC: Total AC for a
> given gene. CONTROL_COUNT_HET: Approximate number of controls carrying
> heterozygous qualifying variants in a given gene CONTROL_COUNT_HOM:
> Number of controlss carrying homozygous qualifying variants in a given
> gene. CONTROL_TOTAL_AC: Total AC for a given gene. P_DOM: p-value
> under the dominant model. P_REC: p-value under the recessive model.

I try to run genetic variant burden test with vcf files and external gnomAD controls. I found this repo suitable and trying to fix bugs now in it.

as a newbie in R statistics, I will be happy about any suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: I am not quite understand what is your goal. It seems that all case file `GENE` is as same as control file. Please clarify more about your intention.

Comment: updated with purpose of the code

Comment: The code should count together heterozygous and homozygous variants per each sample in both cases and controls and then perform Fisher's test.

Comment: Posted at biostars, too: https://www.biostars.org/p/9471698/

Comment: Still not quite clear. Can you please show the example of expected result table based on `casefile` and `controlfile` you gave? (Construct manually to see a pattern is OK)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want all row in two file. You can use full join with by = "GENE" and suffix as you wish

```
library(dplyr)

z <- outer_join(case_file, control_file, by = "GENE", suffix = c(".CASE", ".CONTROL"))

             GENE CASE_COUNT_HET.CASE CASE_COUNT_CH.CASE CASE_COUNT_HOM.CASE CASE_TOTAL_AC.CASE
1 ENSG00000124209                   1                  0                   0                  1
2 ENSG00000064703                   1                  1                   0                  9
3 ENSG00000171408                   1                  0                   0                  1
4 ENSG00000110514                   1                  1                   1                 12
5 ENSG00000247077                   1                  1                   1                  7
6 ENSG00000174776                  NA                 NA                  NA                 NA
7 ENSG00000076864                  NA                 NA                  NA                 NA
8 ENSG00000086015                  NA                 NA                  NA                 NA
  CASE_COUNT_HET.CONTROL CASE_COUNT_CH.CONTROL CASE_COUNT_HOM.CONTROL CASE_TOTAL_AC.CONTROL
1                      1                     0                      0                     1
2                      1                     1                      0                     9
3                      1                     0                      0                     1
4                      1                     1                      1                    12
5                      1                     1                      1                     7
6                      1                     1                      0                     2
7                      1                     0                      1                    13
8                      1                     0                      1                    25
```

2. If you want only GENE that are in both rows, use `inner_join`

```
z <- inner_join(case_file, control_file, by = "GENE", suffix = c(".CASE", ".CONTROL"))

  GENE CASE_COUNT_HET.CASE CASE_COUNT_CH.CASE CASE_COUNT_HOM.CASE CASE_TOTAL_AC.CASE
1 ENSG00000124209                   1                  0                   0                  1
2 ENSG00000064703                   1                  1                   0                  9
3 ENSG00000171408                   1                  0                   0                  1
4 ENSG00000110514                   1                  1                   1                 12
5 ENSG00000247077                   1                  1                   1                  7
  CASE_COUNT_HET.CONTROL CASE_COUNT_CH.CONTROL CASE_COUNT_HOM.CONTROL CASE_TOTAL_AC.CONTROL
1                      1                     0                      0                     1
2                      1                     1                      0                     9
3                      1                     0                      0                     1
4                      1                     1                      1                    12
5                      1                     1                      1                     7
```